# Detectar que un registro a borrar no existe en la tabla SQL (MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

gracias por ayudarme mucho. Tengo una duda algo simple.

Hice un formulario que borra registros de una tabla, funciona correctamente, pero no logro hacer que de un mensaje de error diciendo que el registro no existe, simplemente dice que lo borro (Cuando ese registro no esta, dice que lo borro, cuando no es cierto).

Esto es lo que he hecho hasta ahora.

El html:

```
<div id="borrador"> <!-- La forma de borrar datos -->
<form method="POST" action="disenoclaseborrar.php" style="padding:50px 250px;">
<h1>Escriba el nombre del profesor para borrar su clase</h1>
<input type="text" placeholder="Escriba el nombre del profesor para borrar la clase" name="nombreprofe" id ="nombreprofe" required></input>
<div id="input submit" style="text-align: center;;"><input type="submit"  id="submit" name="submit" class="floated" value="Borrar clase"></input></div>
</form>
```

El php:

```
<?php
$nombreprofe = $_POST['nombreprofe'];
$db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'prueba');
$nombreprofe = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $nombreprofe);

$query = "DELETE FROM reservadiseno WHERE nombre = '$nombreprofe'"; 
$result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
$res = '';

if ($result > 0) {
$res = 'Se borraron los datos. Refresque la pagina para ver la tabla denuevo';
echo $res;
}else{
$res = "No se encontro nada para borrarlo";
echo $res;
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes utilizar [`mysqli_affected_rows`](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.affected-rows.php):

> Obtiene el número de filas afectadas en la última operación MySQL

`int mysqli_affected_rows ( mysqli $link )`

> Devuelve el numero de filas afectadas por la última consulta INSERT, UPDATE, REPLACE or DELETE.

#### Ejemplo:

```
<?php
$nombreprofe = $_POST['nombreprofe'];
$db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'prueba');
$nombreprofe = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $nombreprofe);

$query = "DELETE FROM reservadiseno WHERE nombre = '$nombreprofe'"; 
$result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
$res = '';

// AQUI
if (mysqli_affected_rows($db) > 0) {
$res = 'Se borraron los datos. Refresque la pagina para ver la tabla denuevo';
echo $res;
}else{
$res = "No se encontro nada para borrarlo";
echo $res;
}

?>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, funciono